# Erro o consumir api com o curl php -> 'Failed to connect to demo.d4sign.com.br port 443: Timed out'

Tags: php, api, libcurl

Quando eu vou consumir uma api com o curl php aparece o seguinte erro: Failed to connect to demo.d4sign.com.br port 443: Timed out.

Código do Curl:

```
<?php       
                $tknAPI;
                $cryptKey;
                $curl = curl_init();
            
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://demo.d4sign.com.br/api/v1/list?tokenAPI=' . $tknAPI . '&cryptKey=' . $cryptKey);
                //curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, TRUE);
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, ['Accept: application/json', 'Content-Type: application/json']);
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

                echo $result = curl_exec($curl);
                echo $err = curl_error($curl);
                    
            ?>
```

Comment: se está consumindo um endpoint na porta 443, está usando ssl, tem o certificado instalado? já tentou passar o certificado como paramentro para o curl, por exemplo `-cacert nome-do-certificado.crt`?

Comment: mesmo com o ssl como parâmetro não tinha retornado nem nada no echo mas apareceu com o var_dump($result); Obrigado!